# What to do when user inputs a number greater than max int?

Tags: java, android

```
int chirps = Integer.parseInt( et_Chirps.getText().toString().trim() );
```

`et_Chirps` is and editText containing a number.

If a user enters a number greater than max int the program crashes.

How to resolve this?

Comment: If you really want to support very large numbers, use `long`. If you want to support even bigger numbers, use `BigInteger`.

Comment: If you *don't* want large number, wrap the parsing in a `try...catch` and act accordingly in case of an exception.

Comment: I don't need to support big integers. I need the code to be safe. If I test the code by inputting a number greater than the data type can hold then the program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit length of input text by adding

```
android:maxLength="9"
```

Or you can change `int` to `long` to support higher range